# Saving multiple PIL-created images with a loop funtion

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create multiple random images with PIL, using a loop function, and I want to save them with their respective indices (e.g.: image00.jpg, image01.jpg, image02.jpg, etc).
When I run the code, all images are created on one platform, and saved in one file.
Where is the problem?
Thanks.

```
L_size=[]   
M_loc=[]
M_size=[]

for n in range(10):
    draw.line((100, 1400, 11990, 1400), fill=(255,255, 255), width=50)
    nlv=random.randrange(4,9)
    nmv=random.randrange(6,13)
    for L in range (0,nlv):
        lvl=random.randrange(1374,9616)
        L_loc.append(lvl)
        lvs=random.randrange (171,221)
        L_size.append(lvs)
        lx1=lvl-(lvs/2)
        lx2=lvl+(lvs/2)
        ly1=1400-(4*lvs)
        draw.ellipse((lx1,ly1,lx2,1400), fill=(255,255, 255), outline=(255,255, 255))
    
    for M in range (0,nmv):
        mvl=random.randrange(1374,9616)
        M_loc.append(mvl)
        mvs=random.randrange(60,101)
        M_size.append(mvs)
        mx1=lvl-(mvs/2)
        mx2=lvl+(mvs/2)
        my1=1400-(4*mvs)
        draw.ellipse((mx1,my1,mx2,1400), fill=(255,255, 255), outline=(255,255, 255))
    
    im.save('desktop/pic.jpg', quality=100)
    L_loc=[]
    L_size=[]   
    M_loc=[]
    M_size=[]
```

Comment: You're writing all of the images to the same file.   Don't you want `n` somewhere in that `im.save` command?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you save all images in the same file. you should change the image path for each image:

```
L_size=[]   
M_loc=[]
M_size=[]

for n in range(10):
    draw.line((100, 1400, 11990, 1400), fill=(255,255, 255), width=50)
    nlv=random.randrange(4,9)
    nmv=random.randrange(6,13)
    for L in range (0,nlv):
        lvl=random.randrange(1374,9616)
        L_loc.append(lvl)
        lvs=random.randrange (171,221)
        L_size.append(lvs)
        lx1=lvl-(lvs/2)
        lx2=lvl+(lvs/2)
        ly1=1400-(4*lvs)
        draw.ellipse((lx1,ly1,lx2,1400), fill=(255,255, 255), outline=(255,255, 255))
    
    for M in range (0,nmv):
        mvl=random.randrange(1374,9616)
        M_loc.append(mvl)
        mvs=random.randrange(60,101)
        M_size.append(mvs)
        mx1=lvl-(mvs/2)
        mx2=lvl+(mvs/2)
        my1=1400-(4*mvs)
        draw.ellipse((mx1,my1,mx2,1400), fill=(255,255, 255), outline=(255,255, 255))
    
    im.save(f'desktop/pic{n}.jpg', quality=100) # This will solve your problem!
    L_loc=[]
    L_size=[]   
    M_loc=[]
    M_size=[]
```

Comment: I just tested the code: it creates 10 images, however, the ellipses will be added on to the next image, meaning that if the 1st image has 10 ellipses, the last image will have 100.

Comment: @NYC34 For saving images in different files, the code works. The thing that you are saying is a logical problem that you should handle in your code with erasing the drawn ellipses, sth like this ```ellipse.remove()``` or ```matplotlib.pyplot.clf()```after saving the image!